# Screenshot of the Week #1

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, blog

To go with the Question of the Week on the blog, one idea that has been tossed around is a Screenshot of the Week.

The screenshot could be of anything, for some examples:

- Something cool you built in Minecraft
- A cool victory you had in Starcraft II
- Some interesting easter egg you noticed in a game.

So far as possible, try avoid spoilers in your content, especially if it relates to recently released games.

Post your image and a short (one paragraph) description to go with it.

Comment: I move for a new rule: 1 pic per user per week, or at the very least 1 pic per post

Comment: @Nick I second this motion.   *(Shhh!)*

Comment: are you planning on blogging about this? ;-)

Comment: @IvoFlipse Real life is on top of me atm. Remind me on the weekend. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

I've got a bunch of Recent Minecraft shots; I think these were all taken this week.

[image: Poseidon lookout & lounge at sunset]

[image: Don't make me come down there...]

[image: I survived!]

[image: PAINTINGS]

[image: Me, the resident arsonist.]

[image: Oh boy...]

[image: The Poseidon Lookout & Lounge]

---

That's probably enough spam for now.

Comment: If anyone likes any of these, I'll be able to come up with some info on most of them.  The one of the huge hole in the ocean would be the easiest, I think.

Comment: The burning wooden dome would have been good if not for the magic carpet in the way :( (for future screenshot reference, you can knock those out by breaking them twice, and they won't respawn until you move again)

Comment: But of the ones there, I like the last one, of the lighthouse at day best.

Comment: I would probably pick the second one, if it wasn't as far away...  My bad.

Comment: And you keep telling me you have nothing to blog about?

Comment: @Ivo > Ah...er... You see...  *poof*

Comment: Did you make the ring of fire one, or is that a bug?

Comment: @Scott > The owner made a giant sphere of wood using a mod (not sure which) and I burned it down.

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me of when my infantry got stuck (regular game, only mod is the [Luxury Resource Display mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/is-there-a-list-of-luxury-resources/9816#9816)):

[image: infantry on an island surrounded by ice]

(only submarines and helicopters may enter ice in Civilization V)

Comment: How did you accomplish that?  The only time I've gotten units stuck in funny spots is when being kicked out from open borders.

Comment: @Nick It was a gift from a city-state... and this island was the closest available empty piece of land to that city-state.

Comment: would you consider it blog worthy to talk about things like this? Are there any other 'weird' things you've encountered while playing Civ V?

Comment: @Ivo this specifically is probably not blog worthy, it's just a single rule - that gifted units spawn in the nearest vacant land tile - which sometimes results in the unit spawning in strange places. Not sure what else is there to say about strange civ5 cases...

Comment: well perhaps you have anything else, that would be interesting to share ;-) What on earth keeps you playing that game after all these months :P

Answer (score 1):

[image: Solomon's Boneyard]

God knows who resides in this particular grave...

Game: Solomon's Boneyard

Comment: Reminded me of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNnaRHqtrDQ).